# group_concat to segregate overlapping dates and combine names

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Let me explain the current situation: 
**Table structure and overview of data:** 
I have a table with patient_ids, drug_name, episode_no for each drug and their start and end dates. This is a snapshot of only a single patient. So this patient is using 2 drugs X and Y. The first episode for drug X starts on 2013-01-22 and ends on 2013-04-22. Similarly, since the second drug is also drug X, it is the second episode. When the drug changes, it is considered as the first episode for the the new drug and so on.

| PATIENT_ID | DRUG | EPISODE | EPISODE_START | EPISODE_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 773 | X | 1 | 2013-01-22 00:00:00 | 2013-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 773 | X | 2 | 2013-06-02 00:00:00 | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 |
| 773 | Y | 1 | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2014-01-22 00:00:00 |

**Requirement:** 
I need to create drug regimens for each of the patients. I'll explain how:
If we plot these data in a timeline, we will have something like this:

[image: 2013-01-22 2013-04-22 |------------X--------------| 2013-06-02 2014-03-12 |------------------X-------------------| 2013-10-28 2014-01-22 |----------Y------------|]

Now the regimens need to be created in the following order:

[image: 2013-01-22 2013-04-22 |------------X--------------| 2013-06-02 2014-03-12 |------X-----|---------X+Y------------|-----X------| 2013-10-28 2014-01-22 |----------X+Y-----------|]

In this situation, the regimens will be combination of drugs which are used in a particular period of time. 
Regimen 1: Drug X from dates 2013-01-22 to 2013-04-22, 
Regimen 2: Drug X from dates 2013-06-22 to 2013-10-28, 
Regimen 3: Drug X+Y from dates 2013-10-28 to 2014-01-22, and finally 
Regimen 4: Drug X from dates 2014-01-22 to 2014-03-12.

Finally, in the end the table would be something like this:

| PATIENT_ID | DRUG_TAKEN | REGIMEN_NO | REGIMEN_START | REGIMEN_END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 773 | X | 1 | 2013-01-22 00:00:00 | 2013-04-22 00:00:00 |
| 773 | X | 2 | 2013-06-02 00:00:00 | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 |
| 773 | X+Y | 3 | 2013-10-28 00:00:00 | 2014-01-22 00:00:00 |
| 773 | X | 4 | 2014-01-22 00:00:00 | 2014-03-12 00:00:00 |

NOTE: There is one date in the middle: 2013-04-22 to 2013-06-02, where there were no drugs which were taken by the patient.

I don't understand how to use group_concat to segregate the dates and combine the drugs. Can anyone please help me on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Currently, this does not contain any primary key. The reason is all the data can contain duplicates, and it is difficult to create composite keys as well, because of the same reason- chances of duplication. One thing I can do, is to introduce row_numbers partitioning by the patient IDs. Then the combination of row_number and patient_id can be considered as a primary key

Comment: It seems to me that (patient_id,drug_taken,episode) must constitute a UNIQUE value

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that can also be used I guess. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: The version of MySQL I am using is 8.0.17

Comment: Good, in that case I think it would be simpler to take advantage of the tools available in that version to in effect construct a calendar and match and then group the dates against that - but I'll leave to others to demonstrate that in more detail.

Comment: Ok. Basically, I don't know how to do that. So if anyone has any suggestions to solve this, I would be greatly obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using an archaic version of MySQL, so you'll need to update this to take advantage of the tools available in 8+, in order to construct an equivalent to my calendar table, and the regimen numbering...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(PATIENT_ID INT NOT NULL
,DRUG CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,EPISODE INT NOT NULL
,EPISODE_START DATE NOT NULL
,EPISODE_END DATE NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(patient_id,drug,episode)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(773    ,'X',1,'2013-11-28','2013-12-12'),
(773    ,'X',2,'2013-12-20','2014-01-06'),
(773    ,'Y',1,'2013-12-28','2014-01-03');
```

Query...

```
SELECT patient_id
     , MIN(dt) r_start
     , MAX(dt) r_end
     , drugs
     , i regimen
  FROM
    (
    SELECT dt
     , patient_id
     , drugs
     , CASE WHEN @prev_patient = patient_id 
            THEN CASE WHEN @prev_drugs = drugs 
                      THEN CASE WHEN @prev_dt = dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                                THEN @i:=@i 
                                ELSE @i:=@i+1 END
                      ELSE @i:=@i+1 END
            ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
     , @prev_patient := patient_id
     , @prev_drugs := drugs
     , @prev_dt := dt
      FROM 
      (
       SELECT dt
                   , x.patient_id
                   , GROUP_CONCAT(drug ORDER BY drug) drugs
                FROM dates 
                JOIN my_table x
                  ON dt BETWEEN episode_start AND episode_end
               GROUP
                  BY dt
                   , patient_id
               ORDER
                  BY patient_id, dt
        ) n JOIN (SELECT @prev_patient := null,@prev_drugs := null,@prev_dt := null,@i:=0) vars
        ) m 
        GROUP 
           BY patient_id
            , drugs
            , i
          ORDER BY patient_id, regimen;

+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| patient_id | r_start    | r_end      | drugs | regimen |
+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
|        773 | 2013-11-28 | 2013-12-12 | X     |       1 |
|        773 | 2013-12-20 | 2013-12-27 | X     |       2 |
|        773 | 2013-12-28 | 2014-01-03 | X,Y   |       3 |
|        773 | 2014-01-04 | 2014-01-06 | X     |       4 |
+------------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to use this and will confirm in some time. Just some doubts, what is the "dates" table from which I presume you are selecting "dt" attribute?

Comment: It's just a utility table - a table of dates. It's not necessary in MySQL 8, because you can just create an equivalent data set on-the-fly

Comment: Ok. So basically, the dates table will contain all the episode starting dates from my_table right?

Comment: It's just a table of dates (from 1970 to 2490, as it happens) but, as mentioned, in 8 you don't need this